# JavaFX animation on canvas

Tags: java, javafx

I'm a newbie of Java. I tried to make a simple 'binary search tree' program. I have a problem during making so I'm looking for the answer.
When the program was looking for correct place where I added a number in, I wanted to put 'flickering' function during processing, but it works like this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07pBD.png)
(It's not flickering but just multiplying.)
How can I figure this problem out?

Here is 'add' method that I wrote in controller.

```
public void handleAddAction(ActionEvent event) {
   System.out.println("add ?   ?");
   String key = addfield.getText();
   int length = key.length();
   
   if ( length > 0 ) {
      boolean integerornot = isStringInteger(key, 10);
      if ( integerornot == true ) {
          int intkey = Integer.parseInt(key);
          if (bst.size() > 10) {
              Alert maxerror = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
              maxerror.setTitle("Message");
              maxerror.setHeaderText("The maximum number of nodes is 10.");
              maxerror.showAndWait();
           }else if(bst.contains(intkey)!=null) {
              Alert duperror = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
              duperror.setTitle("Message");
              duperror.setHeaderText("Duplicated numbers cannot be added.");
              duperror.showAndWait();
           }else if (intkey>=0 && intkey <= 9) {
               bst.insert(intkey);
               addfield.setText("");
               DoubleProperty x = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
               DoubleProperty y = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
               
               
                  
               compareNode(bst.root,intkey);
               gc.setStroke(Color.rgb(15, 76, 129));
               gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
               gc.fillOval(width-10, height-15, 25, 25);
               gc.strokeOval(width-10, height-15, 25, 25);
               gc.setFill(Color.rgb(15, 76, 129));
               gc.fillText(key, width, height);
               if(bst.size()>1) {
                  gc.strokeLine(width-ratiowidth, height-50 +(25/2), width-ratiowidth, height -50 +(25/2) +10);
                  gc.strokeLine(width-ratiowidth, height-50 +(25/2)+10, width, height -50 +(25/2) +10);
                  gc.strokeLine(width, height-50 +(25/2) +10, width, height -(25/2));
                  gc.fillPolygon(new double [] {width-5, width, width+5}, new double[] {height -(25/2) -10, height -(25/2), height -(25/2)-10}, 3);
                  
                  Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0),
                              new KeyValue(x, width-ratiowidth),
                              new KeyValue(y, height-50)
                        ),
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10),
                              new KeyValue(x, width),
                              new KeyValue(y, height)
                        )
                  );
                  // timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
                  
                  AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
                     public void handle(long now) {
                        gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
                        gc.strokeOval(x.doubleValue(), y.doubleValue(), 30, 30);
                     }
                  } ;
                  
                  timer.start();
                  timeline.play();
               }
               prekey = intkey;
               height = 20;
               width = 740;
               ratiowidth = 740;
           } else {
              Alert inerror = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
              inerror.setTitle("Message");
              inerror.setHeaderText("Only numbers from 0 to 9 can be added.");
              inerror.showAndWait();
           } 
       }else {
          Alert string = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
          string.setTitle("Message");
          string.setHeaderText("Please insert integer.");
          string.showAndWait();
       }
   }else {
      Alert noinput = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
      noinput.setTitle("Message");
      noinput.setHeaderText("You did not input anything! Please insert value.");
      noinput.showAndWait();
   }
   
   addfield.setText("");
   
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: [mcve] please ..